# Width and Height not doing effect when trying to resize an image inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize my image inside a form but width and height are not doing any effect.

```
.sectionForm {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1914/1914882.svg") no-repeat center center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

```css
.sectionForm {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1914/1914882.svg") no-repeat center center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.sectionForm form {
  width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 66px 0 50px 0;
}

footer {
  height: 1500px;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-container input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
  padding: 26px 0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #4F4F4F;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionForm">
  <form>
    <div class="form-container">
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Nome">
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="E-mail">
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Assunto">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using table so you need `table-layout: fixed;` to adjust the width and you cannot change the height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need in this case is not width and height, but `background-size`.

Try using `background-size: 100px 100px;` one is for width and the other one is for height. You can also use percentages or `background-size: cover` and `background-size: contain` depending on your needs.

Comment: Threres a way to when a set  background-size: 1000px 1000px; the image overflows the div?

Comment: It should overflow, otherwise you can try with percentage values above 100%.

Comment: overflow only in the left and right. but i want also in the top and bottom

Comment: That would depend on your image and container proportions @jarwin you'd have to adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using {

background-size: 100% auto;

}